# Заменить рекурсию циклом C++

Tags: c++, циклы, рекурсия

Возникла следующая ситуация. Реализую свою собственную библиотеку длинной арифметики. Возникла необходимость написать функцию подсчета факториала. Немного поискав в сети алгоритмы быстрого подсчета факториала я нашел не сложный и одновременно быстрый алгоритм подсчета "деревом", вот его код:

```
#include <iostream>


int factorial_tree(int number_thirst, int number_second) {
    if (number_thirst > number_second)
        return 1;
    if (number_thirst == number_second)
        return number_thirst;
    if (number_second - number_thirst == 1)
        return number_thirst * number_second;
    int tmp = (number_thirst + number_second) / 2;
    return factorial_tree(number_thirst, tmp) * factorial_tree(tmp + 1, number_second);
}
int factorial(int number) {
    if (number < 0)
        return 0;
    if (number == 0)
        return 1;
    if (number == 1 || number == 2)
        return number;
    return factorial_tree(2, number);
}
int main() {
    int number;
    std::cin >> number;
    std::cout << factorial(number) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Я изучил этот алгоритм и встроил его в свою библиотеку. Все работает, все хорошо. Однако, в данном алгоритме используется рекурсия и я предполагаю, что при больших значениях факториала (>1000000) возможно переполнение стека. Единственное нормальное решение, которое я вижу - заменить рекурсию циклом. Я пытался это сделать - не получилось. Короче говоря, нужна помощь с заменой рекурсии на цикл в этом алгоритме.

Comment: А что, этот алгоритм быстрее простого перемножения чисел в цикле? За счёт чего? Я вижу только последовательное разбиение диапазона на кусочки до размера 1 или 2, затем сбор результатов с перемножением, и  тем же количеством умножений, что и в примитивном цикле.

Comment: Данный алгоритм быстрее при использовании программной длинной арифметики. Умножение чисел +- равной длины почти во всех алгоритмах длинного умножения выполняется гораздо быстрее, чем умножение чисел резко отличающейся длины.

Comment: Я только что сравнил скорость наивного алгоритма и алгоритма умножения деревом на своей реализации длинной арифметики. В качестве номера факториала я выбрал 100000. Наивный алгоритм работал 55 секунд, алгоритм умножения деревом - 20 секунд.

Comment: Попробуйте эмулировать стек вектором троек чисел -- number_thirst, number_second и tmp

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что значит эмулировать стек вектором.

Comment: Я полагаю, что оптимизация типа "замена рекурсии циклом" в контексте денной задачи - совершенно бессмысленна: потеря времени на вызов 100000 функций (время которое можно сэкономить) менее 0.001(с) много меньше 20с которые длится расчет. Переполнение стека здесь невозможно: глубина рекурсии равна`log(n)/log(2)` для 1000000 она составит 20, а для 1000000000  равна  30, при отсутствии тяжелых объектов на стеке - это тоже пренебрежимо мало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос закрыт. Как верно сказали в комментариях к вопросу, переполнение стека возникнет только на очень неприличных факториалах, а затраты на рекурсивные вызовы минимальны.